# How do I get more seeds from farming?

Tags: timber-and-stone

When I have one seed from farming, I want to get more seeds. How do I do that? I always seem to get one seed back when a farmer collects the full grown crop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your farmers increase in level, they will have better chances of getting more seeds. The total number of seeds you have increases slowly, but it does increase. Early in the game, you'll want to focus on Foraging for food. Farming is more of a late game food source.

Comment: there is always a chance of getting 2 seeds, but yes higher skill improves that chance. I think you should designate a farmer early on otherwise you will be seiged by enemies and then starve

Comment: Oh, yes, designating a farmer early *is* important, so that he can increase his level and get more food/seeds, but it shouldn't be your primary food source at the beginning.

Comment: I have seven farmers on day 26 as well as a herder and two fishermen. I am pretty late in the game, but I just got one cotton seed from a migrant and I need cotton. I don't have a cotton otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, nothing you can do but plant it and hope. Maybe devise a way to make sure your best farmer harvests it.

Comment: All my farmers are level 20 :)